# Fetching all users from Discord server

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've got a problem with fetching the data of all users on the server. Currently, when I tried the first method I'm getting only 21 people (mods, admins, and bots online) instead of all 546 people on it.
I found the second method with `.fetch()` but it gives me 0 users back, so I think that I'm not using it correctly (But it doesn't give me any errors like when I tried to use await and forEach() after). The purpose of this bot is to update a rank for each user on daily basis, the `rankUpAll()` works just fine.

```
const job = new CronJob('29 18 * * *', function () {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(serverId);
  let Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FFC900')
    .setFooter('~~~ qbeczek', 'https://i.imgur.com/xutibOg.png')
    .setTitle('Cześć!');
  let seenUser = 0;
  let listOfUsers;
  guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
    seenUser++;
    // if (member.id == myid) {
    //   rankUpAll(member, guild, Embed);
    // }
  });
  console.log(`Fetched: ${seenUser}`);
  seenUser = 0;
  const wait = new Promise(() => { listOfUsers = guild.members.fetch() });
  Promise.all([wait]).then((values) => {
    listOfUsers.forEach(member => {
      //console.log(member.displayName);
      seenUser++;
      // if (member.id.match(myid)) {
      //   rankUpAll(member, guild, Embed);
      // }
    })
  });
  console.log(`Fetched: ${seenUser}`);
}, null, true, 'Poland');
job.start();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Server Members Intent:
"If your bot tracks server members or downloads the entire member list, you may need the server members intent to receive member events and the member list."

You can read some information about intents here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html

Comment: Do I only need to switch `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` inside discord dev portal or I need to kick and add the bot to the server once again?

Comment: Switch SERVER MEMBER INTENT on inside the panel.

Comment: Still nothing changes, results of first depends on online admins and second still gives me 0 online